# SharedResource Localization and Simple Injector in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, localization, simple-injector

I have an ASP.NET web api in ASP.NET core 2.1 and I have implemented a shared resource as explained [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/). This works fine.

The line :

```
services.AddLocalization()
```

adds localization to the inbuilt IOC container. (I think this is where the magic happens at least)

Now I have added Simple Injector into the mix for my own classes and I have a class which I have registered as Async Scoped which gets injected with the shared resource (through IStringLocalizer). However, IStringLocalizer is scoped as transient and this is not compatible with Async Scoped (as this has a longer scope). I can obviously solve the problem by setting the option **"SuppressLifestyleMismatchVerification"** to true, but this doesn't smell right. (in this case it probably doesn't matter but by using this option I mask any other problems I may have) Is there anyway of fixing this problem? Can I change the scoping of the shared resource for example?

Comment: well - providing original error message along with the code related to the place where IStringLocalizer used would be in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;** override the default registration as follows:

```
services.AddLocalization();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStringLocalizer<>), typeof(StringLocalizer<>));
```

---

What you are seeing is two universes collide; both DI libraries have their own, incompatible, definition of what it means to be *transient*:

- Simple Injector considers components with a `Transient` lifestyle to be short lived, or *brief*. That’s why Simple Injector doesn’t allow transients to be injected into Singleton components; a Singleton could live for a much longer time than would be considered *brief*.

  Simple Injector versions before v5 (which is what OP was using) also restricted injection of transients services into scoped components. With the introduction of v5, however, this behavior as been loosened up a bit, which means transients can now (by default) be injected into scoped components. But still, transients can't be injected into singletons.
- ASP.NET Core / MS.DI does not consider transient components to be short lived *at all*. Instead, the expected lifetime of a `Transient` component in .NET Core is to be *as long as its consumer's intended lifetime*. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes) even state that "This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services."

It is because of this behavior that the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI) container allows injecting transients into both singleton and scoped consumers.

> **SIDE NOTE:** I would even argue that Microsoft named their lifestyle incorrectly, because the actual behavior is to have one instance per consumer's dependency. Microsoft seems to have copied this behavior from Autofac. Autofac, however, does name this same lifestyle `InstancePerDependency`, which is a much more obvious name, if you ask me.

Weird thing, though, is that the Microsoft's `AddLocalization` extension method [registers](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/43b974482c7b703c92085c6f68b3b23d8fe32720/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/LocalizationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L65) `StringLocalizer<T>` as transient. This is weird, because, apart from the wrapped `IStringLocalizer`, `StringLocalizer<T>` doesn't have any state. And not only that, the `IStringLocalizer` that it wraps is produced by the injected `IStringLocalizerFactory` and can be expected to be the same instance (which is enforced by the fact that the `ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory` [caches](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/43b974482c7b703c92085c6f68b3b23d8fe32720/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.cs#L158) returned instances).

As stated above, within MS.DI, `Transient` means “I'll live as long as my consumer does. “ This practically means that a `StringLocalizer<T>` instance can live as long as a singleton, meaning: for the duration of the entire application.

From this respect it is actually really *weird* that the localization team chose `StringLocalizer<T>` to have a transient lifestyle, even in MS.DI. Transient only means more instances created, and the `IStringLocalizerFactory` invoked more often than required. I find `Singleton` a much more obvious lifestyle for that registration.

I would, therefore, suggest *overriding* the default registration with a singleton, as it is safe to do so anyway:

```
services.AddLocalization();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStringLocalizer<>), typeof(StringLocalizer<>));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Steven the clear explanation.
I've written an extension method for localization, and confused with the lifestyle of IStringLocalizer.

```
public static class LocalizerExtensions
{
    private static IStringLocalizer<Localizer> _localizer =  default!;

    public static IServiceCollection AddLocalizer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            string enUSCulture = "en";
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo(enUSCulture),
                new CultureInfo("vi"),
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(enUSCulture, enUSCulture);
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
            {
                var lang = GetLang(context);
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(lang, lang));
            }));
        });
        services.AddSingleton<ILocalizer, Localizer>();
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLocalizer(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _localizer = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<Localizer>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        return app;
    }

    public static string ToLocalizer(this string name)
    {
        return _localizer[name];
    }

    private static string GetLang(HttpContext context)
    {
        var lang = context.Request.Headers["Language"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lang))
        {
            lang = context.Request.Query["Language"];
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lang))
        {
            lang = "vi";
        }
        return lang;
    }
}
```

In method `ToLocalizer`, I used a static instance of `IStringLocalizer<Localizer>`, which means singleton lifestyle, and worried about using it correctly. With your explanation, I can use it without any worries

Answer (score 0):

Its very strange that we need to use DI for IStringLocalizer because it will not be changing on request to request basis. Hence, it will be better if we have a singleton implementation of it. I found another way of implementing IStringLocalizer as singleton. My resource files are in folder "LocalizeResources" and "MessageResources" is a dummy class which I am passing for providing reference to my resource files.

"LocalizationFactoryService" is a static class which creates an instance of IStringLocalizer.

Add the code below to ConfigureService method in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ....
   
   services.AddLocalization(opts =>
        {
            opts.ResourcesPath = "LocalizeResources";
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                    factory.Create(typeof(MessageResources));
            });
    var options = Options.Create(new LocalizationOptions { ResourcesPath = 
                  "LocalizeResources" });
    var factory = new ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(options, 
            NullLoggerFactory.Instance);

   LocalizationFactoryService.SetLocalization(new 
            StringLocalizer<MessageResources>(factory));

}
```

"LocalizationFactoryService" is a static class and we can use GetLocalizer() method to get an instance of IStringLocalizer in any controller/Service class.

```
public static class LocalizationFactoryService 
    {
        private static IStringLocalizer<MessageResources> _stringLocalizer;

        public static void SetLocalization(IStringLocalizer<MessageResources> stringLocalizer)
        {
            _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
        }

        public static IStringLocalizer<MessageResources> GetLocalizer()
        {
            return _stringLocalizer;
        }
   }
```